# Careers' Favorites Page Sorting Is Broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, sorting

I was on the Careers Favorites page again today, and found out that your list of favorites is always sorted by "Date posted" no matter what you select.  Changing it to "Job title" or "Company name" refreshes the page, but doesn't affect the sorting whatsoever.

[Here's a screencast reproducing the issue.](http://screencast.com/t/ktMed8mRd)

I can reproduce in Firefox 18 / Chrome 24 on OSX 10.8.

Comment: Yepp, you found another one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Sorting your favorite jobs won't cause any trouble anymore, we promise!

Comment: `<sarcasm>` **YES**, I can finally go back to firing off resumes in an order that makes sense!`<sarcasm>` I kid, I kid, I really only want to work for you guys. :)